# Using Fetch API with Rails application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fetch

I am trying to use the Fetch API with my Rails application. I can pass parameters to the controller as part of a query string, but still can't figure out how to pass JSON data or where to find it in the controller. A sample call looks like the below. Where can I access my test data on in the controller? Happy Sunday :)

```
    export const fetchControllerData = () => {
      return fetch('api/users',), {
        body: { "test": "test" }
      })
      .then(res => res.json());
    };
```

Comment: I didn't see "test" as params in the controller when I used debugger.

Comment: Apparently get requests can't have a body? `Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.`

Comment: Yes, my question is is it possible to pass JSON, arrays, etc. as params? Your proposed solution works for simple key value pairs, but what if you want to pass other data structures besides strings, numbers, etc.?

Comment: Do you mean passing it through `test=stringifyJSON([1, 2, 3])`?

Comment: I cannot get this to work for JSON objects. On the backend when I look at the parameter I get `"[object Object]"`. How do I get the key value pairs out of that?

Comment: Did you set the method, i.e. `fetch(url, params, { method: "POST" })`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of working out my own issues with fetch and Rails. But I'll take a stab at this.

I expect that `fetch` is using `GET` as the default method - which won't use the body at all. You will likely need to set the method to be `POST` to get the body through. Further to that you might need to set the `Content-Type` header (to `application/json`) in order to send the data through as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

May be u need to send params in this way for get request and use this link for https://github.com/axios/axios

```
 export const fetchControllerData = () => {
   params = { body: { "test": "test" } }
   return HTTP.get('api/users', params)
              .then((response) => {
                 if (response.success) {
                   // do something here
                 } else {
                    // handle error condtion here
                 }
              });
 }
```